# Do I have to call unmount with Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Maybe I'm y bit too careful here. I create a component with `createApp` programmatically and `mount` it on a DOM node. Later, I remove the DOM node from the DOM tree.

Do I have to make sure to call `unmount` before removing the DOM node (with the mounted Vue3 app) in order to avoid a memory leak? Or is all data maintained in properties of the DOM node created during the mount? The documentation doesn't mention this explicitly (or I failed to find anything).

Explicit unmounting seems natural according to general resource allocation/deallocation rules. No need for explicit unmounting also seems natural as this is a garbage collecting environment.

Comment: I found in the documentation that [event listeners are explicitly destroyed](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/events.html#why-listeners-in-html). Do you use `<keep-alive>`?

Comment: Event listeners are removed "when a ViewModel is destroyed". Fine. But what destroys the VM? With vue2 I had the $destroy and knew that I had to use it. Vue3 removes the $destroy and claims that things magically work (https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/introduction.html#removed-apis). I'm always unsure about such claims... (And no, I'm not using keep alive.)